# Add video in Video Editing in Blender

Tags: animation

I have added a video in Video Editing in Blender.
The Source information says that the video Resolution is 720x1280, however when I set the format Resolution to 720x1280 I got a bigger frame, ref the picture.

[image]

Any thoughts?

Cheers

Comment: Have you changed the values under Strip -> Transform -> Scale?

Comment: When you add a video it is scaled to the render resolution. If you change this afterwards, the scale of the video is not changed automatically with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a video in the *Sequencer*, the movie strip gets scaled so that it fits inside the *Resolution X* and *Y* size which you have set for the scene while keeping the video's aspect ratio.

If you now change the *Resolution* to something else, the scaling of the video will not automatically be re-adjusted to fit the new size. You can do it manually under *Strip* > *Transform* > *Scale X/Y*.

Note: It is different if you have set the *Resolution* percentage to something else than 100%. Let's say the resolution is 1920 × 1080 and the video is 1920 × 1080 as well, then it's imported at full frame, original size. If the *Resolution* is set to 50% this will change the size of the render, but setting it back to 100% will not change the size of the video in the frame, because it is scaled to 1 and will be rendered at full frame, no matter if the scene is rendered at 100%, 50%, 25% etc.

[image: scale video]

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Brinkmann, that's vey good explanation, now all makes sense.

Comment: @Larry Glad it helped. Maybe you could consider accepting the answer then.